# 2 sockets interoperation produce "socket operation on non-socket - ENOTSOCK" error

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sockets, http

In a Ruby script I'm having a problem with socket connections.
What I am doing is the following:

- I have two threads and each one creates a connection to a different web server
- Any time thread 1 receives data from server 1, I want thread 1 to post this data to server 2
- Any time thread 2 receives data from server 2, I want thread 2 to post this data to server 1

Basically I am kind of acting as a bridge between the 2 servers.

Code looks like this:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

@connection1 = Net::HTTP.start 'server1.com'
@connection2 = Net::HTTP.start 'server2.com'

# reads data from server 1 as it comes and sends it to server 2     
Thread.new{
  while JSON.parse(@connection1.post('/receive').body) !nil
      @connection2.post '/send', JSON.parse(@connection1.post('/receive').body) 
  end
}


# reads data from server 2 as it comes and sends it to server 2  
while JSON.parse(@connection2.post('/receive').body) !nil
    @connection1.post '/send', JSON.parse(@connection2.post('/receive').body) 
end

# Thread.join 
# not actually needed because the two connections are supposed to continuously stream data
```

However as soon as one of the two connections receives data and tries sending it to the other connection I'm receiving the following error:

**Socket operation on non-socket - Errno::ENOTSOCK**

More in deep stack trace:

> C:/Dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in
>   wait_readable': **socket operation on non-socket. (Errno::ENOTSOCK)**
>           from C:/Dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in 'rbuf_fill'
>           from C:/Dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:154:in 'readuntil'
>           from C:/Dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:164:in 'readline'
>           from C:/Dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in
>   'read_status_line'
>           from C:/Dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in 'read_new'
>           from C:/Dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1446:in block in 'transport_request'
>           from C:/Dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1443:in 'catch'
>           from C:/Dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1443:in 'transport_request'
>           from C:/Dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1416:in 'request'
>           from C:/Dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1430:in 'send_entity'
>           from C:/Dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1218:in 'post'

So what do you think I am doing wrong?

I should add that for reasons beyond my control the two remote servers are configured to serve data when contacted with a POST rather than with a GET.

Answer (score 3):

### Core problem

You lack any sort of synchronization between both threads and `Net::HTTP` is not thread-safe. 
What's possibly happening here is that you call `@connection1.post /receive` in one thread, that said thread gets paused and the second thread tries to use `@connection1.post /send` while `connection1` is still being used.

Another problem is that your code in **inefficient**, you issue two `/receive` requests per thread to get information.

```
while JSON.parse(@connection1.post('/receive').body) !nil
      @connection2.post '/send', JSON.parse(@connection1.post('/receive').body) 
  end
```

*This makes three requests total*

Could be

```
while True
  result = JSON.parse(@connection1.post('/receive').body)
  break if result.nil?
  @connection2.post '/send', result) 
end
```

*This makes two requests total*

---

### Suggested Solution

Use a `Mutex` to make sure that while `connection1` is sending/receiving a request, no other thread touches it.

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

@connection1 = Net::HTTP.start 'server1.com'
@connection2 = Net::HTTP.start 'server2.com'

connection_1_lock = Mutex.new
connection_2_lock = Mutex.new

# reads data from server 1 as it comes and sends it to server 2
Thread.new do
  while True
    receive_result = nil
    connection_1_lock.synchronize do
      receive_result = JSON.parse(@connection1.post('/receive').body)
    end
    connection_2_lock.synchronize do
      @connection2.post '/send', receive_result
    end
  end
end

Thread.new do
  while True
    receive_result = nil
    connection_2_lock.synchronize do
      receive_result = JSON.parse(@connection2.post('/receive').body)
    end
    connection_1_lock.synchronize do
      @connection1.post '/send', receive_result
    end
  end
end
```

I believe the code above should fix your problem, although I cannot guarantee it. Concurrent programming is hard.

---

### Further reading:

I suggest you read up on concurrent/multithreaded programming and its pitfalls. There are numerous Ruby resources online.

Since Ruby's documentation on `Mutex` is notoriously bad, I'll shamelessly plug my own article here and suggest you read it:

https://dev.to/enether/working-with-multithreaded-ruby-part-i-cj3 (The 'How To Protect Yourself' paragraph introduces mutexes)